# How to create UML diagram in Android Studio from Kotlin code?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, uml

I've got Android project and I've tried to generate UML diagram.
These are my steps:

1. Download SimpleUMLCE, istall it and restart IDE.
2. Click on class -> Tools -> Show Kotlin Bytecode, which generates decompiled class: with name className.decompiled.java
3. Right click mouse on generated class name (I want to select option 'add to simpleUML diagram') but I haven't got this option.

[image]

Comment: You better ask in that SimpleUMLCE forum/git/whatever.